# Como verificar se o item está na lista em knockout, porque a função isthere retorna 'false'?

Tags: javascript, knockoutjs

A duvia é a seguinte:
Quando clico no botão **Add To List** este executa a função `addToList` que por sua vez executa a função  `isThere` que está a a returnar **false** e este é exactamente o que não entendo.

```js
function Person(firstName, lastName) {
  this.firstName = firstName;
  this.lastName = lastName;
}

function isThere(list, p) {
  var lista = list;
  var person = p;
  var flag = false;
  var i = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < list.length; i = i + 1) {
    if (lista()[i].firstName == person.firstName) {
       flag = true;
    }

  }
  return flag;

}

function AppViewModel() {
  this.firstName = ko.observable("Bert");
  this.lastName = ko.observable("Bertington");
  this.fullName = ko.computed(function() {
    return this.firstName() + " " + this.lastName();
  }, this);

  this.capitalizeLastName = function() {
    var currentVal = this.lastName();
    this.lastName(currentVal.toUpperCase());
  }
  this.isthere = ko.observable("false");
  this.persons = ko.observableArray([]);
  this.addToList = function() {

    var firstName = this.firstName();
    var lastname = this.lastName();
    var p = new Person(firstName, lastname);
    this.persons.push(p);
    this.isthere(isThere(this.persons, p));

  };

}

ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());


this.capitalizeLastName = function() {
  var currentVal = this.lastName();
  this.lastName(currentVal.toUpperCase());
};
```

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.5.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div>
    <p>First name: <input data-bind="value: firstName" /></p>
    <p>Last name: <input data-bind="value: lastName" /></p>
    <button data-bind="click: capitalizeLastName">Go caps</button>
    <button data-bind="click: addToList">Add To List</button>
    <p data-bind="text: isthere"></p>
    <p data-bind="text: firstName"> </p>
    <p data-bind="text: lastName"></p>
    <p data-bind="text: fullName"></p>

  </div>
  <div>
    <table style="background-color:blue">
      <thead>
        <tr>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody data-bind="foreach: persons">
        <tr>
          <td data-bind="text: firstName"></td>
          <td data-bind="text: lastName"></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

  </div>
</div>
```

[Apenas porque pode ajudar alguem]

[exemplo knockout](https://jsfiddle.net/amadeuantunes/7p2Lz3g4/)

Comment: Provavelmente porque a condição do `if` não está sendo satisfeita.

Comment: isso é o que eu não entendo o porque!

Comment: Coloca um `console.log(lista()[i].firstName, person.firstName)` antes do IF e veja se os valores estão corretos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No for, voce acabou usando `list.length`, quando deveria ser `list().length` ou `lista().length`

---

```js
function Person(firstName, lastName) {
  this.firstName = firstName;
  this.lastName = lastName;
}

function isThere(list, p) {
  var lista = list;
  var person = p;
  var flag = false;
  var i = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < lista().length; i = i + 1) {
    if (lista()[i].firstName == person.firstName) {
       flag = true;
    }

  }
  return flag;

}

function AppViewModel() {
  this.firstName = ko.observable("Bert");
  this.lastName = ko.observable("Bertington");
  this.fullName = ko.computed(function() {
    return this.firstName() + " " + this.lastName();
  }, this);

  this.capitalizeLastName = function() {
    var currentVal = this.lastName();
    this.lastName(currentVal.toUpperCase());
  }
  this.isthere = ko.observable(false);
  this.persons = ko.observableArray([]);
  this.addToList = function() {

    var firstName = this.firstName();
    var lastname = this.lastName();
    var p = new Person(firstName, lastname);
    this.persons.push(p);
    this.isthere(isThere(this.persons, p));

  };

}

ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());


this.capitalizeLastName = function() {
  var currentVal = this.lastName();
  this.lastName(currentVal.toUpperCase());
};
```

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.5.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div>
    <p>First name: <input data-bind="value: firstName" /></p>
    <p>Last name: <input data-bind="value: lastName" /></p>
    <button data-bind="click: capitalizeLastName">Go caps</button>
    <button data-bind="click: addToList">Add To List</button>
    <p data-bind="text: isthere"></p>
    <p data-bind="text: firstName"> </p>
    <p data-bind="text: lastName"></p>
    <p data-bind="text: fullName"></p>

  </div>
  <div>
    <table style="background-color:blue">
      <thead>
        <tr>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody data-bind="foreach: persons">
        <tr>
          <td data-bind="text: firstName"></td>
          <td data-bind="text: lastName"></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

  </div>
</div>
```